# Making a dynamically-created label in Flex/ArcGIS a clickable hyperlink

Tags: apache-flex, click, label, hyperlink, arcgis

I have an ArcGIS map created with Flex. The labels created dynamically are the towns on the map. We have some PDF files that have some information about the towns on the map.

Is there a way to make those town labels clickable so that they can display the PDF information on a new page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way :

```
var u:URLRequest=new URLRequest(pathToPdf); 
navigateToURL(u,"_blank");
```